# Simulating kCFURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet error

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection

I can't seem to cause `NSURLConnection` to raise the kCFURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet error.

I have tried the following:

1. Airplane mode or disable wifi with no 3G. Both returns kCFURLErrorCannotConnectToHost
2. Link Conditioner with 100% in/out packet lost. This returns kCFURLErrorTimedOut

How do I simulate a kCFURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet error?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054117/test-nsurlconnection-failure

seems to be answered there already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get `kCFURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet` you need to have a router with no gateway. What you can do is (if not at a company) unplug the internet backhaul from your router. If you're using the simulator, try temporarily manually assigning an IP address without a gateway.

Comment: Thanks. I got it working by setting to a non-existent router. 

In addition, the error code was different when I was using an IP instead of a domain for the URL while on airplane mode. I had to use a domain name to get `kCFURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet`, otherwise it will be `kCFURLErrorCannotConnectToHost`